# Using Perl's Template.pm, how can I select a random element from an array and output it?

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

Suppose I have the following in my template:

```
[%- pages = [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ] -%]

<p>Go to page [%- ... -%]</p>
```

Assuming `EVAL_PERL` is **not** set (i.e., I cannot use a `[%- PERL -%]` block), what do I need to put inside the `[%- ... -%]` above so as to get the following output?

```
<p>Go to page "a randomly picked element of pages"</p>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't any support for `rand` by default in Template, so you have to either import it via some other code (like [Slash](http://www.slashcode.com/comments.pl?sid=1459&cid=5016)) or use [Template::Plugin::Math](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/modules/Template/Plugin/Math.html), e.g.:

```
[%- USE Math -%]

[%- pages = [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ] -%]

<p>Go to page [%- pages.${ Math.rand(pages.size) } -%]</p>
```

Output:

```
$ tpage test.html
```

```
<p>Go to page three</p>
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about `T:P:M`.

Comment: You are welcome. Once you pointed me to `T:P:M`, the rest was straightforward.

Answer (score 4):

If I have to do anything complex, I just use `[%PERL%]` sections and skip the Template Toolkit syntax.

Additionally, I figure out as much as I can in the controller and pass in a data structure of the values to use. I try to never select values or create new values in the template. Once you move logic into the template, you have to redefine it when you have another set of templates.

Comment: I agree with you on both counts, but in this case I had to fit something in to a very straightforward, existing web site.

Comment: That's the sort of qualifier I put in the question. :)